# Decoder JPEG error while resizing images

Tags: python, image, jpeg

I have written the following code to read jpegs from a directory and then resizing them.

```
for dirs, path, files in os.walk("wallet_training/"):
    for filename in files:
            I=Image.open(os.path.join("wallet_training",filename))
            I=I.resize((256,256), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            print I
```

However it throws the following error:

```
File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
I=I.resize((256,256), Image.ANTIALIAS)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1290, in resize
self.load()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 189, in load
d = Image._getdecoder(self.mode, d, a, self.decoderconfig)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 385, in _getdecoder
raise 
IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
```

When used without the resizing function, the code seems to be working.
Thank You in advance.

P.S. I checked another question, i have libjpeg-dev installed and its still not working

Comment: You seem to be missing PIL. What system are you running? `pip install -I PIL`.

Comment: He's not missing PIL; he's just missing PIL's JPEG support.

Comment: What version of PIL/Pillow are you using? If you're still using PIL, any reason not to switch to Pillow? If you're installing a binary, can you install via `pip` instead? What platform/distro/version are you on, and how did you install `libjpeg-dev`? Are you sure the bit-widths match (e.g., 32-bit `libjpeg-dev` won't help with 64-bit Python and PIL)?

Comment: @Allendar I had PIL installed. :)  abarnert Yes, i installed the binaries using pip, i m using a 64 bit ubuntu 13.10 and i installed 64 bit packages. I switched from PIL to pillow and it worked. Sorry for bothering you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to diagnose why PIL isn't finding libjpeg at build time and using it properly, we could…

But PIL is effectively a dead project, and it has many problems with configuration on systems that didn't exist 4 years ago (like 64-bit Ubuntu 13.10). It also has some problems working with modern `setuptools`/`pip`, and very little documentation on the build process. And the last version of it (1.1.6) never got distributed to PyPI.

[Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org) is "a modern fork of PIL", which started off with PIL 1.1.6, fixed it up to do `setuptools` properly, got it working on every major OS, ported it to Python 3.x, and fixed all kinds of bugs.

So, unless you really need PIL 1.1.5 or 1.1.6, use [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org) instead. Which should be as simple as this:

```
$ pip uninstall PIL
$ pip install pillow
```

Unless you install via binary wheel, the output from that install command should give you a nice table of which features were and weren't compiled in… but if you have your distro's standard `libjpeg` and `libjpeg-dev` packages, I'm willing to bet it'll be found.